# Cron Job with Java.jar creates no File

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, jar, cron

I have a simple Java application on my Ubuntu 16.04 Server. This application generates a prices.txt file. The File is generated if I start it directly with:

```
java -jar TankstellenLogger.jar
```

If I schedule it with cron it doesn´t create that file and I have no Idea why? The file is running because in cron I see the Log.txt which I want to have the other output, but thats not all.

crontab -e

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /home/dominik/startLogger.sh > /home/dominik/Log.txt
```

StartLogger.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/dominik/TankstellenLogger.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"prices.txt" is possibly being written to a directory other than where you're expecting.  Try adding this to the bottom of "startLogger.sh":

```
pwd
ls prices.txt 2>&1
```

That should print the working directory to "/home/dominik/Log.txt" as well as a check for whether "prices.txt" is there.  If that info doesn't show up in "Log.txt", it may be a permissions problem.

Comment: It worked yes. It writes the prices.txt file to /root/.Thank you alot.

Comment: @Theroth, you're welcome.  Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it fixed your problem.